# How to display a blank cell using IF formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I am trying to get cell `H5` to display blank if cell `G5` is also blank

This is the formula I am currently using in `H5` :

`=IF(COUNT(G5)=0,AVERAGE(F5),SUM(F5/G5)),IF(G5,"","")`

This currently returns the `#DIV/O!` error

If anyone could tweak this that would be great.

Comment: What should it display when G5 is not blank?

Comment: What about `IF(G5="","", do something else)`? You can check first if G5 is blank or not. If true, return `""`. IF false, then whatever calculation you need.

Comment: the syntax contains two IF statements separated by a comma, and thus is not a valid syntax

Comment: @AnilGoyal if ```G5``` contains any number (including 0) then ```H5``` should ```SUM``` ```F5``` / ```G5```.

Comment: What do you mean with `SUM(F5/G5)`. What kind of syntax is that? Do you want to simply devide these two cells? Same question for `AVERAGE(F5)`. I do not understand what you are doing here. An average of a single number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try =ISBLANK() in your formula.

Comment: **Note:** *blank* is not the same as a *zero length string*.

Answer (score 1):

`#Div/0` error can show up in your formula because one of the following:

- `AVERAGE(F5)` (if all cells are empty)
- `SUM(F5/G5)` (if dividing by an empty cell)

Try This one:

`=IF(COUNT(G5)=0,IFERROR(AVERAGE(F5),""),IFERROR(SUM(F5/G5),""))`